# How can I differentiate a list between odd and even integers?

Tags: python-3.7

In python, I have 10 random integers from 1 to 25 and I want to sort the numbers into two lists, Odd and Even. Not sure how to tackle this.

I've tried conditional statement to see if it's Odd or Even, that works, but I don't know how to put them into two separate lists.

```py
import random
number1 = random.randint(1,25)
number2 = random.randint(1,25)
number3 = random.randint(1,25)
number4 = random.randint(1,25)
number5 = random.randint(1,25)
number6 = random.randint(1,25)
number7 = random.randint(1,25)
number8 = random.randint(1,25)
number9 = random.randint(1,25)
number10 = random.randint(1,25)
if number1 % 2 == 0:
    number1 == 'even'
else:
    number1 == 'odd'
if number2 % 2 == 0:
    number2 == 'even'
else:
    number2 == 'odd'
if number3 % 2 == 0:
    number3 == 'even'
else:
    number3 == 'odd'
if number4 % 2 == 0:
    number4 == 'even'
else:
    number4 == 'odd'
if number5 % 2 == 0:
    number5 == 'even'
else:
    number5 == 'odd'
if number6 % 2 == 0:
    number6 == 'even'
else:
    number6 == 'odd'
if number7 % 2 == 0:
    number7 == 'even'
else:
    number7 == 'odd'
if number8 % 2 == 0:
    number8 == 'even'
else:
    number8 == 'odd'
if number9 % 2 == 0:
    number9 == 'even'
else:
    number9 == 'odd'
if number10 % 2 == 0:
    number10 == 'even'
else:
    number10 == 'odd'

I didn't get any errors, but I don't know what to do.
```

Comment: You don't have a list here.  You have a bunch of variables.  You want something like `random_int_list = [random.randint(1,25) for i in range(10)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try code below, it makes two arrays (one for odds and other for evens) and add odd and even numbers to them (respectively):

```py
evenArr = []
oddArr = []
for i in range(0, 10):
  number = random.randint(1,25)
  if number % 2 == 0: #means it is even
    evenArr.append(number)
  else: #otherwise it is odd
    oddArr.append(number)
```

I hope it helps;

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
 num = random.randint(1,25)
 mod = num % 2
 if mod > 0:
     listEvenNumbers.append(mod)
 else:
     listUnevenNumbers.append(mod)
```

This will divide every number by two, and if there is no remainder (as it is the case for even numbers), appends it to a list of even numbers. If its not even, it will append it to the list of uneven numbers.